# Splitting code into files using context api

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm using context API for the first time.I can understand how to write the code in a single page.But I can't understand how to split it into several files.When I split it as below it gives me an error saying that I have not exported MyProvider.But I have done it.I searched for many video tutorials but I couldn't find a one that matches to my problem

**App.js**

```
import {MyProvider} from './Context';
import {myContext} from './Context';

class Name extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <myContext.Consumer>
          {(context) => (
            <React.Fragment>
              <h1>Hello, {context.state.name}</h1>
              <h3>{context.state.address}</h3>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
        </myContext.Consumer>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

class Age extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <div>
          <myContext.Consumer>
            {(context) => (
              <React.Fragment>
                <h1>You are {context.state.age} years old</h1>
                <h3>You were born in - {context.state.dob}</h3>
              </React.Fragment>
            )}

          </myContext.Consumer>
        </div>

    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <MyProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <Name />
          <Age />
        </div>
      </MyProvider>
    );
  }

}


export default App;
```

**Context.js**

```
export const myContext = React.createContext();

class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "Sam",
    address: "No.35,Main Street,Galle",
    age: 50,
    dob: "1970-10-21"
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <myContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </myContext.Provider>
    )
  }
} 

export default MyProvider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake in import. When you export as **default**, you should import it without curly braces.

```
export default CLASS

import CLASS from
```

Or you can export your class as export class, then you will import it as you do:

```
export class A

import { A }
```

**UPD:**
Please take a look at

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export